# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/animation/FastOutSlowInInterpolator;

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm facing an issue with my new app. I created a app for shopping cart and i created a signin and signup page and it is now showing error message

Error:

```
08-19 18:56:41.279 2902-2902/com.example.dinidev.ecom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main `Error`
                                                                    Process: com.example.dinidev.ecom, PID: 2902
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dinidev.ecom/com.example.dinidev.ecom.Signin}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                                                        at com.example.dinidev.ecom.Signin.onCreate(Signin.java:16)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/animation/FastOutSlowInInterpolator;
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.AnimationUtils.<clinit>(AnimationUtils.java:30)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:200)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:183)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414) 
                                                                        at com.example.dinidev.ecom.Signin.onCreate(Signin.java:16) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
08-19 18:56:41.279 2902-2902/com.example.dinidev.ecom E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.animation.FastOutSlowInInterpolator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dinidev.ecom-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                            ... 30 more
```

module app:`Build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dinidev.ecom"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}`Code`
```

activity_main xml `It is opening and working properly`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/profile1"
tools:context="com.example.dinidev.ecom.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/guest"
    android:layout_width="168dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/signin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/Guest_User"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen_sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="487dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/signin"
    android:layout_width="178dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/signup"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/signup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen_sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="487dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signup"
    android:layout_width="168dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/New_User"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen_sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="487dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

login_page xml `It is not opening`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/login_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginPage_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fourty_seven_dp"
        android:text="@string/logo"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fourty_four_sp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>
</RelativeLayout> `It is not opening it shows error as app stopped working message`
```

MainActivity class

Main activity is working fine but when I click login it stops action

```
package com.example.dinidev.ecom;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button signin;
final Context context = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

private void addListenerOnButton() {
    /** Login Button Click */
    signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Signin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
```

Signin class

When i debug the line it shows save instance : null message

```
package com.example.dinidev.ecom;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Signin extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
}
}
```

Androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dinidev.ecom">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/register_label"
        android:name=".Signup">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/register_label"
        android:name=".Signin">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: you are getting text input error please check have implement all the dependencies correctly, and clean your project and rebuild this then run your app hope it will solve  your issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to include multiDex in your application. In your **manifest**, you have not included the **MulitiDexApplication**.

In you error code. See this line.

```
Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.animation.FastOutSlowInInterpolator" on path: DexPathList[
```

Add this to your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

In your Gradle add `multiDexEnabled` true.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true    // add this line
    }
    ...
}
```

In your `manifest` add multiDex application class.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Finally clean and rebuild your project.

For more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer if it is helped you to resolve your issue. It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0"
```

because google has extract interpolator to this lib.